# Bash Shell Script : Concating lines that do not end in ^M

Tags: linux, shell

This is again a question related to End of line characters in Unix and Windows.

I have a sql extract where some fields can contain text that have line breaks.

When I take this extract to a linux machine and open it in VI with :se list option set I see text like below:

```
   1 some broken Text part 1 - Line1$
   2 other broken text part 2 -line 2^M$
   3 good line ^M$
```

I need to detect lines that do not end in CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) or ^M  and see if it contains value that have line breaks.

In the above extract , basically i need to join the line 1 and line 2 and come up  with just one line

```
1 'some broken Text part 1 - Line1 other broken text part 2 -line 2^M$
```

There should be no change to the Line 3 which would then become the line 2 of the file.

I tried to remove \n using tr but then the whole file became just 1 line in VI.
After removing \n , I tried to then replace \r with \r\n but it introduced unexpected behavior in the file.

Any help to figure out this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: if you're getting your broken text from an SQL query, look at the man page for your SQL client and look for options to change the line length, then you don't have to mess with this ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You could just replace `\n` with a space and `\r` with `\n`:

```
$ printf 'some broken Text part 1 - Line1
other broken text part 2 -line 2\r
goodline\r\n' > file.txt

$ cat -vE file.txt
some broken Text part 1 - Line1$
other broken text part 2 -line 2^M$
goodline^M$

$ tr '\n\r' ' \n' < file.txt
some broken Text part 1 - Line1 other broken text part 2 -line 2
 goodline
```

Comment: I removed '\n' and then replaced '\r' with '\r\n' .. that worked,

Comment: Is it '\n\r' or is it '\r\n' ?

Comment: The posted command produces the posted output. If you want it in DOS format, you can use unix2dos after.

Answer (score -1):

Below did the trick:

```
tr -d '\n' < file.txt > step1-file.txt
sed -i -e 's/\r/\r\n/g' step1-file.txt
```

Somehow the below perl line that i was trying to use earlier was introducing unexpected behavior.

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r/\r\n/' step1-file.txt
```